# Erro 492 al instalar plugin con plug.vim para neovim en windows 10

Tags: windows10, plugin, vim

seguí un vídeo tutorial  donde me indicaban como debía instalar(siguiendo GitHub)

y no puedo solucionar los errores que sale...

**para instalar este esquema de colo puede usar la siguientes formas:(yo use el de vim-plug)**

Use vim-plug agregando a su .vimrcsección vim-plug:

Plug 'dikiaap/minimalist'

Entonces corre :PlugInstall.

**ahora vamos a mi powershell**

```html
all plug#begin()

Plug 'dikiaap/minimalist'


call plug#end()

establecer  t_Co = 256
sintaxis  en
esquema de colores minimalista
~
~
```

luego le doy:     :PluugInstall

y sale el error:          **E492: No es una orden del editor: PlugInstall**

por si ayuda,también encontré algunos errores al aplicar en powershell:

```
PS D:\Users\kraud\AppData\Local\nvim> nvim
```

```html
                                                                                                                        Se ha detectado un error al procesar D:\Users\kraud\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim:
línea    1
E488: Caracteres en exceso al final de la línea: all plug#begin('~/.config/nvim')
línea    3
E492: No es una orden del editor: Plug 'dikiaap/minimalist'
[vim-plug] plug#end() called without calling plug#begin() first
línea    8
E492: No es una orden del editor: establecer  t_Co = 256
línea    9
E33: No existe una expresión regular de sustitución previa
línea   10
E492: No es una orden del editor: esquema de colores minimalista
Pulse INTRO o escriba una orden para continuar
```

Comment: seguro que tienes instalado el gestor de plugins Plug ?

Answer (score 1):

A mi tambien me salia el error `E492: No es una orden del editor: PlugInstall`
Con windows 10

Cuando instalé nvim, se me creó una carpeta en `AppData/Local` llamada `nvim-data`... ahi instalé `vim-plug` con el comando

```
iwr -useb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim |`
    ni "$env:LOCALAPPDATA/nvim-data/site/autoload/plug.vim" -Force
```

Para poder solucionar el error al momento de instalar los plugins, cree una carpeta en `AppData/Local` llamada `nvim`, ahi dentro creé el archivo `init.vim` . Y en ese mismo escribis el código para cargar e instalar los plug-ins y funciona `:PlugInstall`.

Cualquier duda avisame y la vemos.
Saludos